# Paypal what is the different between future payments and orders

Tags: paypal

I have an IOS application that allow customers to purchase items, the items are available in about a week or 2.  I'm trying to understand which payment method is fit my needs.

I read the documentation of Paypal mobile sdk and Paypal rest api and I don't understand what is the different between :

1.Future Payment - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/

2.Place and Order - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-process-order/

Does fureture payment place the funds on hold ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Future Payment

Lets you set up a system where you can charge a PayPal account on demand. No funds are held, you're just given a token to process future charges, after the client authorizes it. This used to be called a Billing Agreement under Classic.

## Orders

Basically lets you charge an authorization up to 10 times (up to 115% of the total amount). You can run this as an authorization to hold funds up to 29 days.